# Start a Process from a C# Application impersonating a specific User

Tags: c#, .net, process

I have a .NET c# application,
the business flow (short and to the point) is:

1. Users make a call to my app which authenticates them by windows authentication.
2. If the user is a "special user" (business logic part, E.g. some account admin), I impersonate to a "Master Account" in the active directory which has read / write permissions to a shared folder.
3. I then create folders and files with the impersonated user context --> This works.
4. But when I try to start a process (bcp.exe for those who care), I can't get it to work!

After many failing attempts , getting many error messages such as "access denied",
and trying to use almost all of the `Process.ProcessStartInfo()` attributes which should assist me to run a process as a different user, I decided to Post this as a question.

I've read many blogs suggesting the only way to do this is to use the win32 dll and call CreateProcessAsUser() method, but it's just to damn complicated, and I couldn't find any working sample of it.

bottom line question:

How can I start a Process (Process.Start) from a c# app while in impersonation context as the impersonated user?

My code:

```
private void ExecuteCommand(string backupSource, string backupFilename, string formatFilename)
{
    // This works --> Here I'm under impersonated user context 
    // with read write permissions to the shared folder
    if (!Directory.Exists(OutputPath))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(OutputPath);
    }

    using (Process p = new Process())
    {
        p.StartInfo = GetProcessStartInfo(backupSource, backupFilename, formatFilename);

        //Here I'm currently getting ""Access Denied" exception"
        p.Start();

        ...
    }
}

private ProcessStartInfo GetProcessStartInfo(string backupSource, string backupFilename, string formatFilename)
{
    var result = new ProcessStartInfo();

    result.UseShellExecute = false;

    result.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

    result.RedirectStandardError = true;

    var file = Path.Combine(PathToExecutable, "bcp.exe");

    // @"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\110\Tools\Binn\bcp.exe";
    result.FileName = file;

    result.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(file);

    result.LoadUserProfile = true;

    result.Domain = "IMPERSONATED USER DOMAIN";

    result.UserName = "IMPERSONATED USER NAME";

    var ssPwd = new SecureString();

    string password = "IMPERSONATED USER PASSWORD";
    for (int x = 0; x < password.Length; x++)
    {
        ssPwd.AppendChar(password[x]);
    }

    result.Password = ssPwd;

    var backupFullFilename = GetFullFileName(backupFilename);

    StringBuilder arguments = new StringBuilder(backupSource);

    var formatFullFilename = GetFullFileName(formatFilename);

    FormatArguments(arguments, backupFullFilename, formatFullFilename);

    var argumentsString = arguments.ToString(); 

    result.Arguments = argumentsString;

    return result;
}
```

**Edit #1:**

I was able to resolve the "Access is denied" exception, by adding the impersonating user to the administrators group on the machine which the application that starts the process runs on.

Now, I'm having a different issue, no exception but seems like the process isn't starting, or exiting right on start, I'm getting exit code 1073741502.

I've read I must use the native win32 api CreateProcessAsUser() instead of System.Diagnostics.Process.Start() but I'm not sure if that's true.

Ideas?

Assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: SQL Server credentials can be set to either use Windows credentials or SQL credentials.  I don't know which you are using.  If you are using SQL credentials, the username and password needs to be put into the argument list.  when using windows credentials sql server will default to user account.

Comment: My problem is specific to the impersonation, If I try to start the bcp.exe process without impersonation (with my machine user), it works, only when I impersonate it fails. I'm mentioning it to clarify I did ran the Process successfully before, I think your response assumes I didn't and the issue is with accessing sql server. Am i correct or did I miss something?

Comment: Impersonating the exe will not change the SQL Credentials.  The credentials will still be in the argument list.  You may not have the proper admin rights to override the SQL credentials that may have a different admin then the one you are using.  Not all admins are equal.

Comment: I was just thinking.  You may have local admin rights on your computer.  The SQL Server could be using a windows credential that is a group account on the network.  If you don't have admin privilege on the network you will get an error.

Comment: Where do I check it (both the group account and the admin privilege)?

Comment: Open SQL Server Management Studio and check credentials.  This will tell you if you are using a windows credential and the windows account name.  Then go into Windows User Account and see if windows account is local or network.  If it is network then you will need to find the password server that is checking credentials.  You will need an admin account on the password server.

Comment: I was able to resolve the "Access is denied" exception, by adding the impersonating user to the administrators group on the machine which the application that starts the process runs on. Now, I'm having a different issue, no exception but seems like the process isn't starting, or exiting right on start, I'm getting exit code 1073741502, and I've read I must use the native win32 api CreateProcessAsUser() instead of System.Diagnostics.Process.Start() but I'm not sure if that's true. Ideas?

Comment: How long does it take for error to occur?  If the error occurs quickly it is occurring during startup, if it takes a while it is during exit.  You can put the bcp into a .bat file and try running from the bat file to make sure the syntax is correct.  I have similar bcp code and run as bat using a background worker because the query takes 30 minutes to finish and it was locking up my Windows Form application.

Comment: It happens instantly during start

Comment: Check event viewer and SQL Server error logs for more info.  Try running from bat file.  Open cmd.exe and run from command prompt to see any error messages.